# Displaying error in External List

Tags: list, bcs

I've an external list. I've to add a new item to the list (insert a record in the db) based on some conditions. Failing to meet those condition I must not allow the creation of object.

I've thrown an exception from the `CreateNewItem` method. Could you please suggest me a mechanism through which I can display a friendly error message and avoid the not so attractive exception message on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly edit the form and add some validation on the form itself using SPD or InfoPath, I have not managed to get rid of those 'beautiful' error messages screens myself.